# Meteor: Animate (Fade In/Out) Dynamic Template Data

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my Meteor template, I am using `each` to iterate over a helper array variable named `asks` whose array contents are dynamically changing. This is displaying properly in Meteor, however, by default, there is no animation to it. The changes are sudden, so it's hard to see exactly what is changing when. I would like to animate these data changes in the template. If `asks[1]` is the same, do nothing. But if `asks[2]` has changed, fade out the old `<tr>` for `asks[2]` and fade in the new `<tr>` with the new `asks[2]` values. How can this be achieved? Thanks!

```
{{#each asks}}
  <tr class="ask">
    <td>{{price}}</td>
    <td>{{amount}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Im newbie, but i would add id=this.id to the trs that would give me handle for animation later and read up on meteor's Ttracker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the _uihooks - here's a great article describing it:
http://www.webtempest.com/meteorjs-animation

Answer (score 0):

Also, this package may be of help: https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-template-animations It is DOM based and internally uses uiHooks, but simpler to use.

Answer (score 0):

Another option added to the mix for animations, which imports [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) can be found here https://github.com/webtempest/meteor-animate.